# How to use the TinyMCE Preview plugin securely?

Tags: security, iframe, tinymce, content-security-policy, tinymce-plugins

When using the Preview plugin, the browser console throws up a warning and an error, due to the plugin rendering the preview area in a sandboxed iFrame with same origin and script permissions (**note that I am self-hosting TinyMCE**):

> An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can escape its sandboxing.

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' localhost:* *.mywebsite.com *.stripe.com *.hcaptcha.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ccbHhlh0ggGPUGgxsrd3RaAKqX6TknPKMclaRo6bcUw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

There isn't any obvious documentation about how this should be handled. The [Preview Plugin Docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/preview/) don't contain any configuration items that might alter this behaviour or any warnings about it.

In addition, the [TinyMCE and CSP page](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/tinymce-and-csp/) doesn't mention any need for the 'unsafe-inline' policy to be allowed on script-src.

## The Content Security Policy on my website

```
default-src 'self' localhost:* *.mywebsite.com *.stripe.com *.hcaptcha.com; style-src *.mywebsite.com localhost:* 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src ws: *.mywebsite.com *.stripe.com; img-src localhost:* *.mywebsite.com *.stripe.com *.hcaptcha.com data: blob:;
```

## The recommended policy from the TinyMCE and CSP page for self-hosting TinyMCE

```
default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' blob:; img-src 'self' data: blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self';
```

Unless I've overlooked something and something in my CSP is the problem here (which seems unlikely, given the iframe warning being thrown, and that it is only script-src that is giving the permissions error), I'm unsure as to how to use the Preview plugin in a way that doesn't enable security vulnerabilities.

I tested this with a TinyMCE editor using no other plugins, and without any content inside the editor, to check if either of those could be causing the issue, but the same errors occur.